# Spring Transaction for management for read and write option of JPA

Tags: spring, multithreading, jpa, transactions, eclipselink

I have little confusion over transaction management and entity manager injection in Spring.

I have an application that reads data from a table and creates relationship  like person has city, search city and assign city to Person object.

Now when I search for city, My City DAO/Repository search city based on different search criteria(zip, name, name/state). Here I ask spring to inject entity manager for query.

again when I am storing my Person object, My DAO of Person is asking to inject Entity Manger,

Now question is how many object of Entity Manger will be created in total and what is impact of this in multi-thread environment, if this is issues what could be better solution

Answer (score 0):

You should have one `EntityManager` instance per "unit of work" (typically a transaction). It can then be garbage collected after your commit. Realistically, this is usually managed by the container, so it will be done behind the scenes.

The `EntityManagerFactory`, on the other hand, should generally only be created once per persistence unit.